# How to achieve full-width headers using UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout but still have content inset of items in section?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Simple stuff that became complicated with `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout`
I want to have a 15px padding on the start and end (left/right) of my sections, so I set contentInset but that causes headers to also have the inset and that looks horrible as cells are visible under both edges of the header.

[image]

If I set `supplementariesFollowContentInsets` to false it gets even worse, as suddenly headers are all over the place. First header slides out of the screen while the rest look good

[image]

Below is the code I use for creating sections and headers.

```
private func preparePlaylistSection(containerSize: CGSize) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection {
    let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1))
    let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
    
    // Size of the group
    let fractionalWidth: CGFloat = 0.42
    let widthHeightAspectRatio: CGFloat = 1.28
    let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(fractionalWidth), heightDimension: .fractionalWidth(fractionalWidth * widthHeightAspectRatio))
    let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitem: item, count: 1)

    return prepareSection(group: group)
}

private func prepareSupplementaryViews() -> [NSCollectionLayoutBoundarySupplementaryItem] {
    // Configure header
    let headerSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1), heightDimension: .absolute(HeaderContentView.estimatedHeight))
    let header =  NSCollectionLayoutBoundarySupplementaryItem(layoutSize: headerSize, elementKind: CollectionHeaderView.kind.supplementaryViewKind, alignment: .topLeading)
    header.pinToVisibleBounds = true
    header.zIndex = 10

    return [header]
}

private func prepareSection(group: NSCollectionLayoutGroup) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection {
    let layoutSection = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
    layoutSection.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .continuous
    // Spacing between items in the group
    layoutSection.interGroupSpacing = 8
    // Content inset of cells
    layoutSection.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 15, bottom: 0, trailing: 15)
    
    layoutSection.boundarySupplementaryItems = prepareSupplementaryViews()
    // False sets supplementary views to a full width but breaks label position for some reason
    layoutSection.supplementariesFollowContentInsets = false // Here lies the problem
    
    return layoutSection
}
```

All sections are created the same way, just with different sizes (first section is the largest, second and third are the same)